# Design pattern in microservice

Tags: design-patterns, architecture, microservices, crud

I'm practicing by designing a Yelp-like app for gyms. In this application, users can create a gym and its related data, and others can review or rate it.

Regardless of app's scale, my question is: how do I design its services in microservice architecture?

Is it a good design pattern to create these three services?

1. Auth service that has a user table and manage user related data for login and registration.
2. Gym service for gym CRUD operation such as posting a gym, updating it, and so on.
3. User service for relating gyms to their owners through event-driven architecture and message broker like Kafka. it also manage user profile data, such as resetting the password or changing the username, email, first name and last name.

If this approach is reasonable, I want to know how does the relationship between user and auth service works. do I need to keep all the user data in the auth service and fetch or update it through published events, or should I duplicate the user data in a new user table in the user service database?

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend you to use microservices based architecture if you're working on a small project, rather a monolith application will benefit you more. If your application gets larger at some point and you feel to separate some modules to make it more request tolerant, then you should go for event-driven architecture and use NoSQL (if possible) based database to easily migrate afterward. Currently, you should only keep your 'Authorization Server' separate from the rest of the APIs. Good Luck.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer my question, I appreciate your point about the monolithic architecture; however, I'm currently practicing microservices. Do you have any other suggestions regarding the structure of my services as described above?